# Transfer SVG paths from XML file to Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I have JS file that draws a logo,and I have to update the logo transferring paths from XML file.So, how can I find the corresponding paths and update them? Here is the link to SVG and JS files https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5JEUwwgKa2iQXpBNFlkd3p0VlU 
Thank you.

Comment: I can't see how the JS file relates to the SVG. File logo2.js seems to be about planets.

Comment: no its the same logo. logo2.js is used to animate(rotate) the logo. "planets" are elements that are rotating and they need to be changed

Comment: OK, I understand. You must add Id's to all 'planets'. Then the XML can find each one and transform it as requested via XML. (Each XML element must include reference to the respective planet's id).